# Visual Basic For Loop how to compare listbox to another listbox?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, for-loop, listbox

So im suppose to make a program on VB that records  numbers into a list box and find the average, and then i am suppose to compare the previous list box numbers and transfer any number that are above average into the other list-box.

Here is my code so far. I am stuck on the part where I have to transfer the numbers that are above average to another list box.

My logic is [show the count of the numbers, then compare the count of numbers to the average, and any numbers that are greater than the average, ill added onto the new list box] but i dont know how to write the syntax.

```
Option Strict On
Public Class frmAverageOfScore

    Private Sub btnRecord_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRecord.Click
        Dim lblscore As Double
        lblscore = CDbl(txtScore.Text)
        lstListofScores.Items.Add(lblscore)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAverage_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAverage.Click
        Dim listScores As Integer = lstListofScores.Items.Count
        Dim sum As Double = 0
        For average As Integer = 0 To (listScores - 1)
            sum += CDbl(lstListofScores.Items(average))
        Next
        txtAverage.Text = (sum / listScores).ToString("N")

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing two routines already provide the foundation for what you need to do. For example, you're already looping through the items in the first list in your averaging routine. Now, just compare each to your average, and populate the second list if they are greater, similar to how you populate the first list.

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To (listScores - 1)
        If (CDbl(lstListofScores.Items(i)) > CDbl(txtAverage.Text)) Then
            lstListofScores2.Items.Add(lstListofScores.Items(i))
        End If
    Next
```

Something to note: There are far more efficient, and readable ways to do this, but I wanted to use code similar to what you've already written. You already know the functionality, you just have to apply it in a slightly different way. Some simple suggestions: store a variable for the average (probably as a Double) so you aren't recalculating it every iteration; use a [For Each](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) loop to iterate the Items in the ListBox instead of a For..Next loop, etcetera.